# Show SQL table other way

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
Code    label    Zone   Price
----    -----    ----   -----
049     able      A       5
100     hui       A       6
049     ddf       B       10
100     dsqf      B       34
```

How can I transform it like this:

```
Code       A         B
----      ---      ----
049        5         10
100        6         34
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "pivot", and there are plenty of questions and answers to be found addressing this - both using standard SQL or using proprietary features of particular database systems - of which we know not which you are using.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - OP has 7 previous questions about SQL Server 2008 so that is a hint. BTW, I tested my answer on fiddle for Oracle and it did not work. Changed the in clause to `'A' as A, 'B' as B` to make it work. Do you know what the standard for this is?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - I only looked at their most recent 5 questions, and none were tagged as SQL Server specifically. `CASE` and `GROUP BY` can generally achieve the pivot, and wrap the `CASE` in the aggregate of your choice. That should work with any standard product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Code, A, B
from
  (
    select Code, Zone, Price 
    from YourTable
  ) T
pivot
  (
    min(Price) for Zone in (A, B)
  ) P
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (assuming a table named 't')

```
  select codeA, A, B from 
   (select code as codeA, price as A from t where zone='A'), 
   (select code as codeB, price as B from t where zone='B') 
   where codeA=codeB
```

Comment: Thanks you, but the result is not 1 ligne

Comment: I don't know how you want to combine multiple A or B prices.  You might want `min(price) as A`, `sum(price) as A` -- it looked to me like there might only be one price per code and zone.  If that's not the case, add a summary.

Comment: your example is work, but when i add Zone C, that mean i have to compare where CodeA=CodeB and CodeA=CodeC

Comment: yeah -- if the number of zones is very large, this isn't a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I havent tested this, but you should be able to do someting like this:

```
SELECT CODE, 
SUM(CASE ZONE WHEN A THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END) AS A,
SUM(CASE ZONE WHEN B THEN PRICE ELSE NULL END) AS B
GROUP BY CODE
```

Comment: Thanks you, but i got Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 8
Syntaxe incorrecte vers ','.
Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 10
Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'where'.